# How to perform inspection of a string representing a function

Tags: python

I need to parse a function represented as a string to extract and validate certain information.

Lets say I have a string representation of the following function:

```
def my_function() -> Dict[str, str]:
    a = {"a": 1}
    return a
```

If I am given this function as a string, how can I perform the following:

- Validate that the return value of the function is a flat dict of strings i.e. Dict[str, str]
- Obtain the keys of the dictionary in the return value as a list of strings (in this case: ["a"])

The string function may be more complicated that the one I'm showing as an example. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use the `ast` module to parse the code, and then process that.

Comment: If the function doesn't return a dictionary literal, you can't verify the return type without actually running it.

Comment: By "string representation" do you mean you have `"""def my_function() -> Dict[str, str]:\n...`?

Comment: So to clarify, since `a` is not `Dict[str, str]`, your parsing of that string representation should do what, exactly? Raise an error?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need this degree of introspection, as opposed to something more simple like running the function and inspecting its output type?

Comment: @ddejohn I can throw an exception yes, I'm just interested in detecting it. In this case I'm interested in detecting that it is wrong

Comment: @ddejohn I can't run the function because I do not know the value of the parameters that the function will receive so I can't run the function. In the example that I gave, the function doesn't receive any parameters. In my current scenario, this won't be the case and I won't know the parameters in advance

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I'm looking into it to see if it is possible to solve my problem